# How to make url "no-follow" for google and other search engines?

Tags: google-crawlers, nofollow

I want to make an url "no-follow" for google and other search engines.

Note: There is no link for this url. So how can i do it? Please help

I have also read about robot.txt. is it related to google "no-follow"?
Please explain and give some detail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide a link so robots don't follow it (typically you'll find this in forums where they don't want people trying to use the forum for their own SEO purposes), just use the `rel` attribute:

```
<a href="/xyz/user" rel="nofollow">user</a>
```

Read more from google [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en).

**EDIT**: 
If you want to hide a complete page (URL) on your site then you can use a *robots.txt* file placed in your public webroot:

*robots.txt*

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /xyz/user
```

You can use an online robots.txt tester like [this one](http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/analyzer/) to confirm it works. (Google has a robots.txt tester as well).

Comment: There is no anchor tag for this url

Comment: You mean you just have text on a page?

Comment: I am using this url directly on browser.

Comment: I want to make this url "http://example.com/xyz/user" no-follow. How to do it in robots.txt?

Comment: Thanks! I will check it

Comment: is it also work if there are parameter like. "http://example.com/xyz/user?x=1&y=2"